Brand new to ag-grid, downloaded community, getting error can't import the export AgPromise
Installed ag-grid community, when I add an import
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
and try to run, I get the following error
./node_modules/ag-grid-react/dist/package/index.esm.mjs Can't import the named export 'AgPromise' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
Following versions installed:
PS F:\Projects\reactApps\grid-test-app-01> npm view react version
18.3.1
PS F:\Projects\reactApps\grid-test-app-01> npm view ag-grid version
18.1.2
PS F:\Projects\reactApps\grid-test-app-01> node -v
v16.13.0
PS F:\Projects\reactApps\grid-test-app-01> npm -v
8.1.0
When I comment out the import, the error goes away.  Did the usual google, etc, haven't found anything.
Tried looking up version compatibility issues ag-grid, react etc.
I did read through the getting started tutorial before starting.

Try version 31.1.1

Thank you. That worked! How can I find working versions and compatibility issues?

You can browse the issue list on github, or they’ve got a list of bugs they are working through on their website. However, I found a good version by just plugging in several recent ones from the release list when I was upgrading recently
